# casting using reinterpret_cast causes: OverflowError: signed integer is less than minimum

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

im casting

```
char* something= reinterpret_cast<char*>(&GPBuffer);
```

and than back to:

```
char temp1 [400];

string buffer = reinterpret_cast<string&>(temp1);
```

I know it looks stupid to cast string to char* but this is what i need and it works!!

but if i pass the "something" (throw internal que) to a different thread, and i try to cast back, i receive:

> 0x00000000009bb2dd in std::basic_string, std::allocator >::operator= (this=0x48410790, __str=Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 469, in to_string
>       return self.val['_M_dataplus']['_M_p'].string (encoding, length = len)
>   OverflowError: signed integer is less than minimum
>   ) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/basic_string.h:486

anyone is familiar with this error?

Comment: syntax for is reinterpret_cast<std::string>(temp1).  but more importantly, you really shouldn't do that.  i suggest you do some more reading - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ and also http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: thanks: casing was there, but due to editing you couldnt see it. i fixed it now.

Comment: What I mean is that there are multiple things wrong.  You should google tutorials about c-strings and std::strings.  But in general, a std::string will accept a null-terminated string without requiring casting.  Again, just look up some C or C++ tutorials related to strings.  https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+string+tutorials&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: What that's telling you is that a `std::string` is not equivalent to a `char *`. Look up the class definition of `std::string`, and you'll find that, while it contains a `char *`, there are other things in there, too, and interpreting random stuff as those other things is going to hurt... Also I'm not sure `reinterpret_cast<reference_type>` should even be valid - even if it's valid, I'm having a hard time imagining it's utility...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take a plain char array, cast it to string, and just expect it to work? You're braver than I thought.

Anyway, the error you're getting comes from the debugger's Python script that tries to print a std::string in a readable form. Since what you have is anything but a valid std::string, some check in the script triggers and throws the error. It's not a normal C++ error.

Comment: thanks. by the way the casting works. only after passing it to other thread it gives me trouble. now i know why.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `void*`

```
void* something = (void*)(&PGBuffer);

string my_fancy_string((char*)something)
```

Besides that, I wouldn't use a std::string for keeping buffers of raw data and just use a char array for that, but that's your choice.

Comment: Agreed.  I suppose one would need to determine the intent of the code.  If it's supposed to store data, one could leverage ostringstream::read and ostringstream::write - or plain ol' memcpy to vector<char>